# C++ writing UTF-8 on Linux

Tags: c++, utf-8, internationalization, fopen

I have the following code on Windows written in C++ with Visual Studio:

```
  FILE* outFile = fopen(outFileName, "a,ccs=UTF-8");
  fwrite(buffer.c_str(), buffer.getLength() * sizeof(wchar_t), 1, outFile);
  std::wstring newLine = L"\n";
  fwrite(newLine.c_str(), sizeof(wchar_t), 1, outFile);
  fclose(outFile);
```

This correctly writes out the file in UTF-8.
When I compile and run the same code on Linux, the file is created, but it is zero length.  If I change the fopen command as follows, the file is created and non-zero length, but all non-ASCII characters display as garbage:

```
  FILE* outFile = fopen(outFileName, "a");
```

Does ccs=UTF-8 not work on Linux gcc?

Comment: This probably because your console has a different character set to the utf-8

Comment: _"The behavior is undefined if the mode is not one of the strings listed above. Some implementations define additional supported modes  (e.g. Windows)"_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen  So `ccs=UTF-8` is a MS extension.

Comment: How can I change the fopen command on Linux to ensure that it writes out UTF-8?

Comment: One way would be to first convert the wchar_t to a byte (`char`) array of UTF-8 encoding units.  Then write out that UTF-8 encoding unit array.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of that?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the extensions done on Windows do not work on Linux, OS-X, Android, iOS and everywhere else. The Microsoft just makes those extensions to achieve that you write incompatible code with other platforms.

Convert your wide string to byte string that contains UTF-8, then write the bytes to file like usual.
There are lot of ways to do it but most standard-compatible way is perhaps like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

using Converter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t>; 

int main()
{
    std::wstring wide = L"Öö Tiib ";
    std::string u8 = Converter{}.to_bytes(wide);
    // note: I just put the bytes out to cout, you want to write to file
    std::cout << std::endl << u8 << std::endl; 
}
```

[Demo is there.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0eab26df31928e6d)  It uses g++ 8.1.0 but g++ 4.9.x is also likely fine.

Note that is rare case when anyone needs to use wide strings on Linux, most of code there uses utf8 only.

Comment: Super.  This worked for me. With a name like "Öö" you must be an expert in special character handling!  Thanks again! 