# How set a FILE* object coding format when using the fopen create a new file?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, fopen

I develop a macos app on my mac , there is some information that I need write to my log.txt file, and the information contain Chinese and English string, so I use the fopen method to create the log.txt :

```
 FILE * m_pFile = fopen(filename, "a+, ccs=UTF-8");
```

but when open the log.txt , it shows me messy code in the Chinese string :

the original Chinese string is '当前启动次数是------',

and the string in log.txt is 'ÂΩìÂâçÂêØÂä®Ê¨°Êï∞ÊòØ---',

what should I do, if want to print the Chinese and English string in log.txt file correct, thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you using to view the file? Because those bytes look more of less correct for UTF-8. Maybe the program you are using to view the file does not understand UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [C++ writing UTF-8 on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890630/c-writing-utf-8-on-linux)

Quote:

> the extensions done on Windows do not work on Linux, OS-X, Android,
>   iOS and everywhere else. The Microsoft just makes those extensions to
>   achieve that you write incompatible code with other platforms.
>
> Convert your wide string to byte string that contains UTF-8, then
>   write the bytes to file like usual.